# Linq Query with join on subquery

Tags: c#, linq

Basically I'm trying to write a query where it joins on select top 1 from a second table so something like:

```
SELECT Sum(pinfo.quantity + p.itemcount), 
   i.owner 
FROM   invoice i 
   JOIN purchase_info pinfo 
     ON pinfo.invoice = i.invid 
   JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT sku, 
                         productlineid, 
                         itemcount 
         FROM   products WHERE productlineid in (13, 14)) p 
     ON p.sku = pinfo.item 
WHERE i.owner = 22623 
GROUP BY i.owner
```

Here's my pathetic attempt in linq that has somewhat invalid syntax, any ideas would be much appreciated.

```
(from i in _invoiceRepository.Table
 join pi in _purchaseInfoRepository.Table on i.InvoiceId equals pi.InvoiceId
 join p in (from p2 in _productRepository.Table where p2.Sku == pi.Item select new { p2.Sku, p2.ItemCount }).Take(1)
 on pi.Item equals p.Sku

 where i.MemberId == memberId &&
 (p.ProductLineId == (int)ProductLines.InkCartridges ||
  p.ProductLineId == (int)ProductLines.TonerCartridges)
 select pi.Quantity * p.ItemCount)
.DefaultIfEmpty(0)
.Sum();
```

Comment: I am a little unsure what the final result is suppose to be? `pi.Quantity * p.ItemCount'? Is one of those suppose to be a price multiply by quantity maybe?  Are you trying to get a total price for an invoice?

Comment: lets just say the system is a bit confusing, while there's a quantity in an order there's also a certain number of items that come in a package so I'm trying to get the total number of items purchased (items * quantity). The problem is that I need to join on sku and sku is not unique, so I desire to join on the first viable sku rather than all of the skus.

Comment: So you want to get the total number of items purchased on a line item (product) on an invoice (order)?  Is the data being populated from a database (I am curious if this is Linq/entity frameworks where it has links to referenced tables already or if the joins have to be done by hand.)  For example does _invoiceRepository.Table.First().Invoice exists?

Comment: Updated the sql query to a query that does what I'm actually trying to do if that helps. _invoiceRepository.Table.First() will return an invoice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my first stab at this.

From the sql, it looks like you want to find how many Ink and Toner Cartridges a particular customer has ordered from you ever.

This should give you the same results as the sql (this is depending on the order of the Products table since we are taking the top 1 without some sort of ordering being done:

```
  var count = from i in _invoiceRepository.Table
              where i.OwnerId == memberId
              select new
                {
                  OwnerId = i.OwnerId,
                  TotalProductCount = i.Purchases.Sum(pro => pro.Products
                                                      .Where(p => p.ProductLineId == (int)ProductLines.InkCartridges || 
                                                        p.ProductLineId == (int)ProductLines.TonerCartridges)
                                                      .Take(1)
                                                      .Sum(p => p.ItemCount * pro.Quantity))
                };
```

Since I did not know the the classes of the three objects (Invoice, PurchaseInfo, and Product) I made a guess at what they are:

Invoice Class: I assume it has a list/collection of PurchaseInfos

```
public class Invoice
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int OwnerId { get; set; }

  public List<PurchaseInfo> Purchases { get; set; }
}
```

PurchaseInfos: An invoice has multiple PurchaseInfos, each one links to (ideally) one product but since the SKU is not unique I assome that this has a list/collection of Products in it.

```
public class PurchaseInfo
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int Quantity { get; set; }

  public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
  public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }

  public int Item {get;set;}
  public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Product Class:  I assome that there is an Id field (not shown) or a composite primary key somewhere

```
public class Product
{
  public int Sku { get; set; }
  public int ProductLineId { get; set; }
  public int ItemCount { get; set; }

  public List<PurchaseInfo> PurchaseInfos { get; set; }
}
```

Hopefully you can take this a get what you need.  If this is way off, please update question with the class definitions (you can remove unneeded properities if you want) so a better answer can be produced.